# Array match /compare VBA Excel / SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, excel, vba

I have 2 arrays, one of which is the array where I got the headers with sql, and the other is a multiple array where I saved the headers list before. my aim is to match the titles list with the array I have taken, the multi array I prepared and found in the excel sheet, and if there is such a title list in the references list, and getting the tables with sql and saving to right page. but my code give error and i cant find a solution.

```
Dim mrow, i, x, As Integer, ftitle As Object, sbhuc, vfields As Variant
x = 0
ReDim vfields(1 To Rec.Fields.Count)
For Each ftitle In Rec.Fields
x = x + 1
vfields(x) = ftitle.Name
Next ftitle
mrow = sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
'multi array 
ReDim sbhuc(1 To mrow)
sbhuc = sheet1.Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(mrow, x + 1)).Value2
 
For i = 1 To mrow
If sbhuc(i) = vfields Then GoTo okpart ' : error :  Run-time error '9': Subscript our of range
Next i
.
.
.
```

[picture of sbhuc array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2FZ3.jpg)

[picture of vfields array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jZiA.jpg)

Can u help me about code (comparing/matching) or another solution for matching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub demo()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastrow As Long
    Dim arField, bOK As Boolean
    
    ' test data
    arField = Array("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD")
    'arField = rec.Fields
    
    With Sheet1
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        i = 0
        Do
            ' check first field
            i = i + 1
            If .Cells(i, 2) = arField(0) Then
                bOK = True
                ' check other fields
                For j = 1 To UBound(arField)
                   If .Cells(i, 2 + j) <> arField(j) Then
                       bOK = False
                       Exit For
                   End If
                Next
            End If   
        Loop While bOK = False And i < lastrow
        
        ' result
        If bOK Then
           MsgBox "Header found row " & i, vbInformation
        Else
           MsgBox "Header not found", vbExclamation
        End If
        
   End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: i like it and I'm aware but what I want to say is that when comparing one array to another array, comparing all the elements of the array feels silly. When comparing an array with another array, there must be a way to compare it completely. If the array we have is 100 or even 1000 elements and the number of arrays we need to find is 100, wouldn't we waste a lot of time?

Comment: @FatihÖZER You can join the array elements into strings `s=Join(ar,"~")` and compare them. If its a 2D array you need to transpose it to a 1D array.  That would also take time. The loop only compares elements till 1 fails so not every element is compared which speeds it up.

Comment: thank you brother, i like join() function, and i'll try to use it in another way

Answer (score 0):

This is array dimension error. With

```
   ReDim sbhuc(1 To mrow)
   sbhuc = sheet1.Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(mrow, x + 1)).Value2
```

sbhuc has been converted into a 2-dimensional array, you should access it with another index:

```
  Dim j As Integer

  For i = 1 To mrow
    For j = 1 to x + 1
      If sbhuc(i, j) = vfields(j) Then GoTo okpart ' : error :  Run-time error '9': Subscript our of range
    Next j
  Next i
```

The defining `ReDim sbhuc(1 To mrow)` is useless.

Comment: I think you meant vfields(i) instead of vfields :)

Comment: yes, vfields(j)?

Comment: yes, sorry bro :)